# error BC30107: 'MsgBoxResult' is an Enum type and cannot be used as an expression

Tags: vb.net

im trying to catch up on my compsci homework and i cant get it right. with this task im supposed to create a button, which outputs Hello World. (this is Visual Basic windows form app) and ive tried searching for a solution but havent found any.im not sure how to fix this. i can give more details if you ask :)

i keep getting the error

error BC30107: 'MsgBoxResult' is an Enum type and cannot be used as an expression.

heres my code so far:

````
    Private Sub startBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles startBtn.Click
        MsgBoxResult("Hello World")
    End Sub
End Class```
````

Comment: `messagebox.show()`  `MessageBoxResult` is the button clicked on the message box

Answer (score 2):

The class you're looking for is the MessageBox class ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.messagebox)), specifically you want to use the MessageBox's Show method ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show?#System_Windows_Forms_MessageBox_Show_System_String_)) which returns a DialogResult ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.dialogresult)).

However, based on the simplicity of your requirement, it doesn't appear that you need to handle the DialogResult.

Here is an example:

```vb
Private Sub startBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles startBtn.Click
    MessageBox.Show("Hello World")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`MsgBoxResult` is (as the word “Result”) a result returned by the function `Interaction.MsgBox` and is an `Enum` wich include 7 states

```
    Ok = 1     
    Cancel = 2       
    Abort = 3       
    Retry = 4       
    Ignore = 5      
    Yes = 6       
    No = 7
```

Then the code assume sense in a scenario like this:

```
   Private Sub startBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles startBtn.Click
        If MsgBox("Hello World ", MsgBoxStyle.OkCancel) = MsgBoxResult.Ok Then
            'Do something 
        Else
            'Do something else
        End If
    End Sub
```